# shall I put "will" in these two following sentences?

Tags: tense, present-tense, clauses, future-tense, subordinate-clauses

Shall I put "will" in these two following sentences?

Students who (will) graduate tomorrow will work in the factory three years later.

Police should make sure if there is(will be) terrorists tomorrow.

Thanks so much!

Comment: In the first sentence, _will_ is not necessary between _who_ and _graduate._ It is difficult to understand what you are trying to express in the second sentence. Why would police want to ensure that there are terrorists tomorrow?

Comment: Thanks so much! Because there will be a sports meeting tomorrow. And sorry for making a mistake! I mean Police should make sure if there is (will be) no terrorists tomorrow. Shall I put "will be"?

Comment: For your first sentence, we don't use "will" when specifying something like that - it's just "the students who graduate tomorrow".  For your second sentence, I think you mean "The police should make sure there are no terrorists", not "if there are no terrorists".

Comment: You should use the [edit] link to add the word _no_ to your question. See @stangdon 's astute comment: this misunderstanding of the use of _if_ is common among new learners of English.

Comment: But can I say: Police should make sure whether there are terrorists or not tomorrow. Without" will"  thanks so much!

Comment: @moyeea Please use the [edit] link to change your question to include the word **no** in the sentence about "Police." Do you understand where the [edit] link is?

Comment: @P.E.Dant Thanks for your recommendation.  Here my sentence has the same meaning with "make sure whether there are terrorists or not." I think the meaning is clear.